# Modify proguard-android.txt for Parcelables

Tags: java, android, proguard

I'd like proguard to obfuscate harder the Parcelable classes so I have changed my file at:

**${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt**

```
-keep class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

with

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  public static final android.os.Parcelable$Creator *;
}
```

and seems to work without problems or crashes after the modification but, is that correct? If yes, why is not this the default config?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your improved configuration is fine. The static `CREATOR` field may be declared as an extension of `android.os.Parcelable$Creator`, so the following is a bit more robust:

```
-keepclassmembers class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
  static ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate more on "an extension of android.os.Parcelable$Creator" i had issues with proguard and android sdk (${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt
) approach and had to fallback on your solution but i would like to understand the reason behind it better. Thanks

Comment: @forcewill The original configuration keeps all public static fields with the exact type `Parcelable$Creator` (not extensions; which can be a problem). The improved configuration keeps all static fields with the name `CREATOR` (irrespective of their precise types). That should cover all cases.

Comment: thanks alot for the explanation, so there is no syntax for in ProGuard for "extension of type" ?. Weird that the fellows at Google make that "mistake" of using `Parcelable$Creator` instead of `static ** CREATOR;`